# Run a task after a given interval in a background service

Tags: java, android

I have this background task i have created

```
package com.cnn.service;

/**
 *
 * @author USER
 */
import android.app.Service;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AndroidStartServiceOnBoot extends Service {

      @Override
      public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
                // do something when the service is created
      }
}
```

and this other file

```
package com.cnn.service;

/**
 *
 * @author USER
 */
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;

// here is the OnRevieve methode which will be called when boot completed
public class BootCompleted extends BroadcastReceiver{
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 //we double check here for only boot complete event
 if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
   {
     //here we start the service             
     Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, AndroidStartServiceOnBoot.class);
     context.startService(serviceIntent);
   }
 }
}
```

I have this task that runs every second

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        Runnable runable = new Runnable() { 

            @Override 
            public void run() { 
                try{
                    //do your code here
                    //also call the same runnable 
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
                finally{
                    //also call the same runnable 
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); 
                }
            } 
        }; 
        handler.postDelayed(runable, 1000);
```

I want to perform some http post every second in my background service. 
Where should i place my code in the `BootCompleted` class?.

Comment: In `AndroidStartServiceOnBoot` class

Answer (score 0):

In the onCreate method of the service class